# Less verbose type for map_err() closure argument?

Tags: rust

Is there a less verbose way to specify the type of the `err` argument for the closure in `map_err()`?
In many other cases the type is inferred.

```
use std::convert::TryInto;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError {
    pub msg: String
}

fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), MyError> {
let some_usize: usize = 0;
let some_i32: i32 = some_usize
    .try_into()
    .map_err(|err: <i32 as std::convert::TryFrom<usize>>::Error| MyError{ msg: err.to_string()})?;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                 remove this and it doesn't compile.
    Ok(())
}
```

Of course, the code `some_i32 = some_usize as i32` works, and surprisingly, using `i32::try_from(some_usize).map_err(...)` DOES infer the type of `err`. So, I do have alternatives, but I'm still curious if there's an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the `From` trait for your error type.

```
impl From<std::num::TryFromIntError> for MyError {
    fn from (err: std::num::TryFromIntError) -> Self {
        Self{
            msg: err.to_string()
        }
    }
}
```

And then pass in `MyError::from` to `map_err`

```
let some_i32: i32 = some_usize
    .try_into()
    .map_err(MyError::from)?;
```

This would also allow for implementing the `From` trait for multiple types that you want to map into `MyError`.

Comment: I'm learning something new with every reply. Would work will for a frequently used error type. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::num::TryFromIntError`. It doesn't prevent the type annotation, but it does make it more bearable.

```
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::num::TryFromIntError;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError {
    pub msg: String
}

fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), MyError> {
let some_usize: usize = 0;
let some_i32: i32 = some_usize
    .try_into()
    .map_err(|err: TryFromIntError| MyError{ msg: err.to_string()})?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not going to mark this (or any) as accepted answer as the next suggestion is equally interesting.  Did you find this TryFromIntError in the documentation, or did you happen to know this (from other code)?

Comment: I found out by looking at the source code for `i32`'s impl for `TryFrom<usize>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can help out Rust's type inferencing by splitting up the the problematic lines, and including a type annotation.

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError {
    pub msg: String
}

fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), MyError> {
    let some_usize: usize = 0;
    let some_i32: Result<i32, _> = some_usize
        .try_into();
    let some_i32 = some_i32
        .map_err(|err| MyError{ msg: err.to_string()})?;
    Ok(())
}
```

But honestly, I recommend just using `try_from` instead of `try_into`

```rust
let some_i32 = i32::try_from(some_usize)
    .map_err(|err| MyError{ msg: err.to_string()})?;
```

Comment: Ah, yes, also interesting. More surrounding type specifiers to help inference. 
Thanks both of you, so far. It helps me in my learning of rust.